# How to get proper column types in Sybase

Tags: sql, sybase, sap-ase, system-tables

I have to know the data type of some columns in my table in Sybase ASE. Here is my query

```
select name from systypes
where type in (39,
47,
39,
39,
106
)
```

this returns

```
char       
varchar    
sysname    
nchar      
nvarchar       
decimaln       
longsysname
```

I was hoping it would return

```
varchar
char
varchar
varchar
decimaln
```

why are the results not as expected ? How can i get the proper column types ? I intend to use this information later to create a dynamic query that creates another table.

Comment: May I ask why you tag MySQL when it's a Sybase specific question?

Comment: What makes you thing the actual result is wrong? Hoping rarely fixes coding errors.

Comment: Look at the systypes table. `type = 39` gives 4 results : varchar, sysname, nvarchar, longsysname. SO the result is as your request expects them to be.

Comment: but when i created the table, i specified the column type as varchar

Answer (score 1):

You need to join systypes to syscolumns on both the type and usertype columns.