# Getting column type from sybase SQL

Tags: sql, sybase

Where I can get column type name from sybase iq SQL

```
select * from syscolumn
select distinct column_type from syscolumn --- value is only R
```

Where can I get like int, varchar, etc..?

```
select * from systypes
```

How to relate with syscolumns?

Comment: I think you want the usertype column.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27567890/how-to-get-proper-column-types-in-sybase

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since MS SQL Server share a lot of design features with Sybase and this works with MS SQL Server it should work with Sybase ASE too (although I haven't tried it due to lack of Sybase server):

```
select c.name as column_name, t.name as type_name 
from syscolumns c
join systypes t on c.type = t.type
```

Looking at the Sybase Adaptive Server Enterprise 15.7 documentation for [syscolumns](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc36274.1570/html/tables/X14340.htm) and [systypes](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc36274.1570/html/tables/X14340.htm) this seems correct.

Comment: Unfortunately i have not syscolumns, i have in the database syscolumn (without 's'). I want to select sc.column_name,st.name from systypes st, syscolumn sc where _??__.

Comment: @user2301515 Are you saying the query doesn't work? Which version of the Sybaser software are you using?

Comment: I have version Sybase IQ 15.2.

Comment: This doesn't work as systypes is not unique on the type column.